# Create group with REST?

Tags: 2013, rest

In the CSOM documentation on MSDN (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj246523.aspx) it looks like the SP.GroupCollection.add method has a REST endpoint: `http://<sitecollection>/<site>/_api/web/sitegroups/add(parameters).`

When I try to Access this uri I get page not found so I guess it has not been implemented?

Does anyone know if it is possible to create new groups and assign permissions to them using the REST api? I know I can do this with CSOM, but I'm trying to get this to work from a workflow. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To add a group via the REST API you need to send a JSON string as a body of a POST request to:

```
http://<server>/<site>/_api/Web/SiteGroups
```

The format that the endpoint expects is the following:

```
{
    "__metadata": {
        "type": "SP.Group"
    },
    "Title": <name>,
    "Description": <description>
}
```

This will return the information of the newly created group or the error if one occurs.

Comment: All of them follow this pattern: __metadata object with the type and other information. But one can't just guess what is needed: so is there some source where you found this documented? Thanks!

Comment: The fields in the corresponding CSOM object provides useful hints! (to help answer my own question).

Answer (score 0):

This page has a wealth of information, but still lacks a really simple example. (It's like they expect everyone to be a heads down keyboard jockey that can read all the mumbo jumbo.)

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn531432.aspx#bk_GroupCollection